# Prevent Eclipse from removing * when organizing imports

Tags: eclipse

Generally, I use `import [static] foo.*` when I actually want to import everything from `foo`. So I'd like Eclipse's Organize Imports to keep any imports with `*` as is and not to replace multiple separate imports with `*`. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

You can set the number of static imports needed to use `*` on `Preferences > Java > Code Style > Organize Imports`.

Comment: I am aware, but this is different: if I set it to 1, Eclipse will use `*` for _all_ static imports, even if I have separate imports originally.

Comment: I believe that is all there is

Answer (score 3):

better late then never.

(Eclipse EE 2020-06)

Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Organize Imports:

at the bottom of the window :
Number of imports for .* (...)
Number of static imports for .* (...)

both are set to 99, set them to 2.

The second import from the same package will automatically shorten both imports into a single wildcard import (i.e. the one with '*')